# reactjs condition rendering function for the code

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o38fu.png) this is output for this code i need a code to be corrected for when i click check box button it should return the values with available as yes

```js
        
        class ProductCategoryRow extends React.Component {
          render() {
            return (<tr><th colSpan="2">{this.props.category}</th></tr>);
          }
        }
        
        class ProductRow extends React.Component {
          render() {
            var name = this.props.product.stocked?
                this.props.product.name:
            this.props.product.name;
                 return (
              <tr>
                <td>{name}</td>
                <td>{this.props.product.price}</td>
                 <td>{this.props.product.available}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          }
        }
            
        
        
            class ProductTable extends React.Component {
              render() {
                var rows = [];
                var lastCategory = null;
                console.log(this.props.inStockOnly)
                this.props.products.forEach((product) => {
                  if (product.name.indexOf(this.props.filterText) === -1 || (!product.stocked && this.props.inStockOnly)) {
                    return;
                  }
                  if (product.category !== lastCategory) {
                    rows.push(<ProductCategoryRow category={product.category} key={product.category} />);
                  }
                  rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.name} />);
                  lastCategory = product.category;
                });
                return (
                  <table>
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>available</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
                  </table>
                );
              }
            }
        
        
            class SearchBar extends React.Component {
              constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.handleFilterTextInputChange = this.handleFilterTextInputChange.bind(this);
                this.handleInStockInputChange = this.handleInStockInputChange.bind(this);
              }
              
              handleFilterTextInputChange(e) {
                this.props.onFilterTextInput(e.target.value);
              }
              
              handleInStockInputChange(e) {
                this.props.onInStockInput(e.target.checked);
              }
              
              render() {
                return (
                  <form>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Search..."
                      value={this.props.filterText}
                      onChange={this.handleFilterTextInputChange}
                    />
                    <p>
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.props.inStockOnly}
                        onChange={this.handleInStockInputChange}
                      />
                      {' '}
                      Only show products with available
                    </p>
                  </form>
                );
              }
            }
        
        
        
            class FilterableProductTable extends React.Component {
                  constructor(props) {
                    super(props);
                    this.state = {
                      filterText: '',
                      inStockOnly: false
                    };
                    
                    this.handleFilterTextInput = this.handleFilterTextInput.bind(this);
                    this.handleInStockInput = this.handleInStockInput.bind(this);
                  }
                
                  handleFilterTextInput(filterText) {
                    this.setState({
                      filterText: filterText
                    });
                  }
                  
                  handleInStockInput(inStockOnly) {
                    this.setState({
                      inStockOnly: inStockOnly
                    })
                  }
                
                  render() {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        <SearchBar
                          filterText={this.state.filterText}
                          inStockOnly={this.state.inStockOnly}
                          onFilterTextInput={this.handleFilterTextInput}
                          onInStockInput={this.handleInStockInput}
                        />
                        <ProductTable
                          products={this.props.products}
                          filterText={this.state.filterText}
                          inStockOnly={this.state.inStockOnly}
                        />
                      </div>
                    );
                  }
                }
                
                
                
        
        
        var PRODUCTS = [
              {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$49.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football',available:'yes'},
              {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$9.99', stocked: true, name: 'Baseball',available:'yes'},
              {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: false, name: 'Basketball',available:'no'},
              {category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch',available:'yes'},
              {category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5',available:'yes'},
              {category: 'Electronics', price: '$199.99', stocked: true, name: 'Nexus 7',available:'no'}
            ];
        
            
    
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      <FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS} />,
      document.getElementById('container')
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="container" />
```

the question is when i click check box it should return only with the values(name,price,available) for which column contains  available value as "yes"
how to implement an if function in reactjs i was getting an error in this code?
pls help me with this solution

Comment: split your code to chunks.. Each component has its chunck with title.. Make you code more readable

Comment: hhh. yes .. i am with you

Comment: no need to add image, because i edit your question, and now, you can run the code on live ..Try it and enjoy.

Comment: @user3880989 did you run the snippet edited by abdennour check that, that the change u want ?? one more thing delete ur unnecessary comments, it will help someone who wants to check the problem and see the status by the comments :)

Comment: want to edit a javascript code(solution) mainly in class (productrow) @MayankShukla

Comment: hey anybody help me to find an solution@AbdennourTOUMI